# How to delete cookie using IOwinContext in OwinMiddleware and .Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin, middleware

is there possibility to remove cookie based on cookie name in OwinMiddleware?

I know that IOwinContext has own cookie abstraction based on Set-Cookie Header and HttpContext has own HttpCookieCollection. In my middleware I don't have access to HttpContext therefore I can't set: `Response.Cookies["userId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`

Using IOwinContext I tried to do following: 
`Context.Response.Cookies.Delete("userId");
Context.Response.Cookies.Append("userId", "");`
but it doesn't work.

There is any working example how can I achieve my goal?
Thank you so much for your help and hints.

Answer (score 0):

Oki that was my fault, because I tried to delete cookie which had diffrent domain.

This piece of code solved problem:

```
Context.Response.Cookies.Delete("userId", new CookieOptions
                    {
                        Domain = "DomainName"
                    });
```